# Maya python connect to multiple input

Tags: python, input, maya

I’m really sorry if I’m asking a question that’s been already answered but I couldn’t find an answer.

I’m writing a code that would allow me to connect a translate of several controllers into a blendWeighted node input channels. The amount of the controllers may vary depending on the selection. I’m struggling with the part where they need to connect to a single blendWeighted node input. Could someone tell me how I could connect every new controller to the next input channel of the blendWeighted node?

I’m sorry if my code is a bit childlike, I’m still learning ^^;

```
sel = mc.ls(sl=True, fl=True)
drvConnect = []

for i in sel:
    name = i.split('_Crv')[0]
    dGP = mc.createNode('transform', n='%s_Drv'%name, p=i)
    drvConnect.append(dGP)
    sh = mc.listRelatives(i, shapes=True)[0]
    blendX = mc.createNode('blendWeighted', n='%s_X'%name)
    blendY = mc.createNode('blendWeighted', n='%s_Y'%name)
    blendZ = mc.createNode('blendWeighted', n='%s_Z'%name)
    mc.connectAttr(dGP + '.translateX', blendX +'.input')
    mc.connectAttr(dGP + '.translateY', blendY +'.input')
    mc.connectAttr(dGP + '.translateZ', blendZ +'.input')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to create a single *blendWeighted* node. If that's the case, consider that the *blendWeighted* node's `input` attribute is an array attribute, so if you want to connect multiple items to it you would need to specify the target index.

For example, to connect the three `translate` outputs of a node to the first three `input`s of the blend node you would use something like this:

```py
mc.connectAttr('ctrl.translateX', 'blend.input[0]')
mc.connectAttr('ctrl.translateY', 'blend.input[1]')
mc.connectAttr('ctrl.translateZ', 'blend.input[2]')
```

(Maya will take care of creating the items in the array)

In our case you could simply keep a counter of the added items while you loop through the selection and the transform components (just a guide - not tested):

```py
sel = mc.ls(sl=True, fl=True)
drvConnect = []

blendNode = mc.createNode('blendWeighted', n='blend_main')

for i in sel:
    name = i.split('_Crv')[0]
    dGP = mc.createNode('transform', n='%s_Drv'%name, p=i)
    drvConnect.append(dGP)

    for comp in ('X', 'Y', 'Z'):
        mc.connectAttr(
            '{}.translate{}'.format(dGP, comp),
            '{}.input[{}]'.format(blendNode, blendIndex))
        blendIndex += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will try this!